# Can't find Ubuntu Bash Root directory in Windows 10

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10 on my PC, but I cannot find my root directory in which the bash works in. I know that it should be located in

```
C:/Users/[Username]/Appdata/Local/Lxss
```

but it's not there. I have verified that my files exist but the directory does not show, even with hidden files shown. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Please DO NOT access the Linux filesystem from Windows: Read this for more info: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/

We are working on improving filesystem interop in future releases, but for now, if you want to share files between Windows & Linux, store the shared files in the Windows filesystem, and access them from Linux via `/mnt/c/...`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to copy a file from Windows desktop to Ubuntu user directory and I was searching for Ubuntu root directory using Windows file explorer.

Later I realised that Windows folders can easily be accessed from Ubuntu bash.

Windows directories can be found under `/mnt/c/Users/YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/`

EX: if you want to access desktop then => `/mnt/c/Users/YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/Desktop`

Later I used `cp` command to copy files from Desktop to Ubuntu like this:

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/YOUR_USERNAME_HERE/Desktop
cp filename.ext ~/
```

`~/` => this directly refers to Ubuntu user directory.

**Tip**: Same thing can be done for moving files from Ubuntu to Windows as well.

Answer (score -2):

This happened to me, because I removed bash and reinstalled it from Windows store.

The work around I used was to create a shortcut of

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\lxss
```

and pasted it into

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\
```

Now my applications on Windows (such as Atom) can access project files made from Ubuntu bash.

Comment: Please DO NOT access the Linux filesystem from Windows: Read this for more info: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/

Comment: A better way would be to push your Ubuntu work into a Windows directory for your other applications to access.